# Qt button not appearing in main window

Tags: c++, qt

(Note: I started learning Qt yesterday and I did my search before asking this.)

After a bit of playing with Qt Designer I decided to make a more serious program, all programatically. Whereas before, simple taskes seemed.. simple, now, diaplaying a button is hell of a complicated because it doesn't show up.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    PixelPeep p;
    p.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

pixelpeep.h - relevant part

```
class PixelPeep : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PixelPeep(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QToolBar * toolBar;
    QHBoxLayout * toolbarLayout;
    QToolButton * addButton; // add new image

    QScrollBar * zoomBar;
};
```

pixelpeep.cpp - relevant part

```
PixelPeep::PixelPeep(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(600,375);

    toolBar = new QToolBar;

    addButton = new QToolButton;
    addButton->setGeometry(20,20,20,20);

    toolBar->addWidget(addButton);
    toolbarLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    toolbarLayout->addWidget(addButton);
}
```

After all this, I get an empty window.

Possible cause, AFAIK:

- button would go out of scope after being created in the class constructor - it's not the case here because it's dynamically allocated and pointer by the private member addButton
- not being in a layout or having size 0 - it's not the case since both of these were addressed in the code

What else could it be?

Sorry for such a noob question...

Comment: you don't set the layout of the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `addToolBar(toolBar);` inside the `PixelPeep` constructor.

You didn't set any icon on your button so it will appear as invisible. Hover over it and you will see it's there:

[image]

Comment: Gosh, that was easy. Thank you.